# How can I save a list of address object with an user object from thymeleaf form?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a student model and in that model i have list of address. How to create a thymeleaf form where I can insert multiple address.

```
public class Student{
   Long Id;
   String name;
   @OneToMany(cascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
   List<Address> listOfAddress = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Address{
   Long Id;
   String homeAddress;
   @ManyToOne
   User user;
}
```

Comment: This is not coding platform rather will be happy to provide you solutions to issues.

Comment: I am not asking for any sort of code, just one to get idea how can i handle that situation in thymeleaf form

Comment: There are many examples of this: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields -- this question is not specific enough.